# OSX Discover which ports an app is using?

Tags: macos, networking, command-line

I have an app running (let's call it MySpecialWebServer.app).
While I have a GUI way to find out what port it's listening for requests on, I'd like to find out using the command line.  I really have no idea how to go about it :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lsof -i
```

will show you a list of all open connections.

```
lsof -i | grep LISTEN
```

will show you a list of all ports being listened on. The left most column indicates the process listening.